# Multiple record in firebase, reusing the previous generated id in callback function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to do something like this

```js
//doing some stuffs
const Adress = {
street: 'strong',
town: 'kinshasa'
}

const Student = {
  name:'ghost',
  phone_number:'081xxxxxxx'
}

MyFirebaseAdressRef.push(Adress, () => 
  {
    //get the genererated key by firebase
    Adress.Id = //the generated key
    Student.adress = Adress
    MyFirebaseStudentRef.push(Student)    
  })
 //doing some stuffs
```

How can i get the generated key inside the callback function. I'm using react and firebase realtime database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you even tried logging the response from `.push()`?

If you had, you would have seen that the key is part of the response returned to you - which you access just like normal JS objects with `.key`

```
this.afd.list('listNameHere').push({
  prop: value,
  prop: value,
  prop: value
}).then( response => {
   console.log(response.key);
});
```